# Determining a ScaleAnimation pivot

Tags: java, android, animation, kotlin, scale

I have a view that I am scaling over list that simulates list item scaling vertically to fullscreen.

Here's example github **[project](https://github.com/kidwon24/ItemList)** to play with **the animation code is [here](https://github.com/kidwon24/ItemList/blob/master/app/src/main/java/mom/example/itemlist/adapters/ItemListRecycleViewAdapter.kt)**

[image]

the code looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/growView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/fiftyBlack" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and

```
view.setOnClickListener {

    val listItemHeight = it.measuredHeight
    val toolBarHeight = (it.parent as RecyclerView).y
    val scalingView = it.rootView.findViewById<View>(R.id.growView)
    val screenHeight = (scalingView.parent as FrameLayout).measuredHeight

    // Position the view exactly over the list item
    scalingView.y = it.y + toolBarHeight
    scalingView.layoutParams.height = listItemHeight
    scalingView.layoutParams = scalingView.layoutParams

    /* 
      pivots[0] scales example animation for the first item of the list 
      for xxhdpi: 1080p device
      for the rest of the visible items the pivots are: 1.954f, 3.131f .... +1.177 (no scroll)
    */ 
    val pivots = arrayListOf(0.777f)
    val itemScale = screenHeight.toFloat()/listItemHeight


    val scaleAnime = ScaleAnimation(1f, 1f, 1f, itemScale,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, pivots[0])
    scaleAnime.setDuration(400);
    scaleAnime.setFillAfter(true);
    scalingView.startAnimation(scaleAnime);
```

As you may see the problem is in determining the y pivot point for each item:

```
val scaleAnime = ScaleAnimation( /.....* Dynamic vertical pivot */)
```

I am struggling a few days to determine the pivot point but can't figure out on what it depends.

Any ideas what it might be?